# Detecting if JSP loads for the first time

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, setattribute

I want to implement a single JSP markup page that is a form like this:

**JSP: formPay.jsp**

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/Pay.do"%>" method="post" id="guest">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><span class="required">*</span> First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%= request.getAttribute("firstname") %>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    [...]
    </table>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Confirm" name="btnConfirm">
</from>
```

**Servlet: PayCommand.java**

```
public class PayCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public HttpServletRequest execute(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        boolean errorWithField = false;

        String paramFirstName = "";
        String paramLastName = "";
        String paramEmail = "";
        String paramCity = "";
        String paramAddress = "";

        try {
            paramFirstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
            paramLastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
            paramEmail = request.getParameter("email");
            paramCity = request.getParameter("city");
            paramAddress = request.getParameter("address");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("jsp", "formPay");
            return request;
        }   

        if (paramFirstName==null || paramFirstName.equals("")) {
            errorWithField = true;
        }
        if (paramLastName==null || paramLastName.equals("")) {
            errorWithField = true;
        }
        if (paramEmail==null || paramEmail.equals("")) {
            errorWithField = true;
        }   
        if (paramCity==null || paramCity.equals("")) {
            errorWithField = true;
        }
        if (paramAddress==null || paramAddress.equals("")) {
            errorWithField = true;
        }

        // if errorWithField==true, reload the formPay.jsp
        if (errorWithField) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "You have to fill out all of the fields.");

            request.setAttribute("jsp", "formPay");
            request.setAttribute("firstname", paramFirstName);
            request.setAttribute("lastname", paramLastName);
            request.setAttribute("email", paramEmail);
            request.setAttribute("city", paramCity);
            request.setAttribute("address", paramAddress);

        } else {           
            // if not, go to the confirm page, everything is ok.
            request.setAttribute("jsp", "confirmation");
            request.setAttribute("firstname", paramFirstName);
            request.setAttribute("lastname", paramLastName);
            request.setAttribute("email", paramEmail);
            request.setAttribute("city", paramCity);
            request.setAttribute("address", paramAddress);
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the JSP loads for the first time, I would like it to be interpreted as if there was no error but `errorWithField` turns out to be `true` so then the error message shows even before the user gets to fill out the form.

The second problem is that the JSP will take the values for the fields that were filled out but will return `null` if there was nothing there, including the first time the JSP loads. How can I treat this problem?

**EDIT**
Please note that `Pay.do` form action is redirected to `PayCommand.java`, which is dealt with the Front Controller pattern. (not shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first question, I think you can use another .do action only for forwarding to the jsp page without setting the attribute errorWithField to true.
2. The second question, you can try this:

   <%= request.getAttribute("firstname") == null ? "":request.getAttribute("firstname") %>

Comment: Thank you for the answer for problem 2, for problem 1, I ended up creating a hidden field in the JSP file.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a hidden field to the form, and check to see whether it has a value.  If it does, then the form is being posted back; otherwise, it's the first load (and you should skip the error checking stuff).